# Terraform aws assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-azure, assume-role

I have a problem with AWS assume role using terraform.

In AWS I have three accounts: root, staging and production (let's focus only on root & staging account) in single organization. The root account has one IAM user `terraform` (with `AdministratorAccess` policy) which is used by terraform to provisioning all stuff.

### [The image of organization structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJRrk.png)

```
Root account ID: 111111111111
Staging account ID: 333333333333
```

A terraform script looks like that:

```
############## backend.tf

terraform {
  required_version = "0.12.19"
}


############## providers.tf
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"

  profile = "default"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = ">= 2.44"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "default"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/staging-admin"
  }

  allowed_account_ids = ["333333333333"]

  alias = "staging"
}


############## organization.tf
resource "aws_organizations_account" "staging" {
  email = "staging@domain.com"
  name  = "Staging"

  parent_id = "ZZZZZ"
}



############## data.tf
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_staging_role" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    resources = [
      aws_iam_role.staging.arn
    ]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "administrator_access" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
}

data "template_file" "cross_admin_trust_policy" {
  template = file("templates/cross_admin_trust_policy.json")

  vars = {
    staging_account_number = aws_organizations_account.staging.id
  }
}



############## iam.tf
resource "aws_iam_role" "staging" {
  name                 = "staging-admin"
  description          = "Assumable role granting administrator permissions to the staging account"
  assume_role_policy   = data.template_file.cross_admin_trust_policy.rendered
  max_session_duration = 20000

  provider = aws.staging
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "staging_admin_access" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.staging.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.administrator_access.arn

  provider = aws.staging_ireland
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "staging_attach_assume_any_admin" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.staging.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.administrator_access.arn

  provider = aws.staging_ireland
}
```

and my policy.json file:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${staging_account_number}:role/staging-admin"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

when I execute `terraform plan` I'm getting this error:

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.aws_iam_policy.administrator_access: Refreshing state...
aws_organizations_account.staging: Refreshing state... [id=333333333333]
data.template_file.cross_admin_trust_policy: Refreshing state...

Error: The role "arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/staging-admin" cannot be assumed.

  There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
    * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
    * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
    * The role ARN is not valid

  on providers.tf line 25, in provider "aws"
```

Someone has an idea how to fix?

Answer (score 4):

According to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/

1. Run the `aws sts get-caller-identity` command to check your identity.
2. Run the `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/staging-admin` command to see if this role can be assumed by your identity.
3. Check your IAM role's trust relationship. You should restrict it so that the IAM role should be only assumed by specific IAM users.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:: 333333333333:root" },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have a problem on the second point. 

1. The `aws sts get-caller-identity` returns me a correct json response

2. The command `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/staging-admin --role-session-name terraform` returns me: 

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/terraform is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/staging-admin`

3. On which account it should be done? On IAM terraform user on root account?

Comment: it seems to me that you should grant your IAM user `arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/terraform` permission to access `arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/staging-admin`. I think you can go to `333333333333:role/staging-admin` this role to set up trust relationship.

Answer (score 0):

According to the data you provided you don't have a role, and you trying to add roles with first apply. Correct me if I'm wrong.
You need to manually create an "account aws role" in IAM with "AdministratorAccess" policy attached.