# How to allow an assume role connect from EC2 to EKS on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

[image]

I created an EC2 instance and an EKS cluster in the same AWS account.
In order to use the EKS cluster from EC2, I have to grant necessary permissions to it.

I added an instance profile role with some EKS operation permissions. Its role arn is `arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/ec2-instance-profile-role`(A) on dashboard. But in the EC2 instance, it can be found as `arn:aws:sts::11111111:assumed-role/ec2-instance-profile-role/i-00000000`(B).

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "11111111",
    "UserId": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:i-000000000000",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::11111111:assumed-role/ec2-instance-profile-role/i-00000000"
}
```

I also created an `aws-auth` config map to set into Kubernetes' system config in EKS, in order to allow the EC2 instance profile role can be registered and accessible. I tried both A and B to set into the mapRoles, all of them got the same issue. When I run `kubectl` command on EC2:

```
$ aws eks --region aws-region update-kubeconfig --name eks-cluster-name

$ kubectl config view --minify
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aw1.aws-region.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:aws-region:11111111:cluster/eks-cluster-name
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:aws-region:11111111:cluster/eks-cluster-name
    user: arn:aws:eks:aws-region:11111111:cluster/eks-cluster-name
  name: arn:aws:eks:aws-region:11111111:cluster/eks-cluster-name
current-context: arn:aws:eks:aws-region:11111111:cluster/eks-cluster-name
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:aws-region:11111111:cluster/eks-cluster-name
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - aws-region
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eks-cluster-name
      - --role
      - arn:aws:sts::11111111:assumed-role/ec2-instance-profile-role/i-00000000
      command: aws
      env: null
      provideClusterInfo: false

$kubectl get svc
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

I also checked the type of the assumed role. It's `Service` but not `AWS`.

It seems this type is necessary.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:: 333333333333:root" },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

[Terraform aws assume role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59704676/terraform-aws-assume-role/59705497#59705497)

But I tried to create a new assume role with `AWS` type and set it to Kubernetes' `aws-auth` config map, still the same issue.

How to use it? Do I need to create a new IAM user to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- name: external-staging
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - exec
      - test-dev
      - --
      - aws
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eksCluster-1234
      - --role-arn
      - arn:aws:iam::3456789002:role/eks-cluster-admin-role-e65f32f
      command: aws-vault
      env: null
```

this config file working for me. it should be `role-arn` & `command: aws-vault`

Comment: You are using aws-vault. I can't use it on my EC2. Since I can't create new allowed user there.

Comment: Yes i am using the AWS vault.